Google OAuth in react opens and stay blankwhite page In production
I have my react application where I added the necessary imports, and while when running on localhost:3000 with the client ID, clicking the login button, opens a pop-up choosing the email and then the popup closes, and then redirects to my onSuccess method,
In Production, I created a new oAuth key, using this client ID, I see the button, I'm able to click on the button and choose the account, and then there is just a white page with no redirect to my side
Im using https://myDomain, If I didn't add the domain to the oAuth, I was getting error when clicking on the button, so adding the domain helps, I'm able to proceed but I don't redirect back to the onSuccess Message
 <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="MY_CLIENT_ID">
            <GoogleLogin
              onSuccess={handleGoogleSuccess}
              onError={() => setErrorMessage("Google Login Failed")}
            />
          </GoogleOAuthProvider>

Im using this.
While locally I don't have any issues, in Production, I see a white blank page.
Did anyone see this before?
My domain is working on SSL, and the domain I inserted in OAuth is working, but getting white blank page
